# Can you tell if Google sign-in had 2fa?

Tags: google-signin

On a web app using Sign-in with Google, I want to know if Google had let the user in with 2fa challenge or without and decide to present a 2fa challenge to the user if they have not. Is there a way to know that?

Failing that, is there a way to tell if the user has 2fa enabled on their Google account or not (regardless of it being part of the most recent login session)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesnt tell you if the user has 2fa enabled on their account or not.

The only information you are going to get back from a google sign in is if it went though or not.